# .net linq update time part of datetime for multiple records

Tags: c#, linq

I have a booking table in my database and one of the columns is booking_date_time. How do I go about updating the time part for multiple records? For example, if I have 5 records that have different dates, I want to keep those dates, but set the time to 10am.
Below is the code I'm using, but this would set the date the same for all objects. I'm hoping to avoid retrieving the list of objects and iterating through them and updating them one at a time

```
booking bookingToUpdate = db.bookings.Where(a => a.booking_recurrence_id == bk.booking_recurrence_id).SingleOrDefault();
bookingToUpdate.booking_date_time = bk.booking_date_time;
db.Entry(bookingToUpdate).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
retVal = db.SaveChanges() > 0;
```

The input data is one booking record (bk). This contains a unique booking_id. It also contains a booking_recurrence_id which links multiple bookings together.

Say I have the following:

> booking_id: 1 booking_recurrence_id: 1 booking_date_time: 1/1/2016
>   08:00
>
> booking_id: 2 booking_recurrence_id: 1 booking_date_time: 2/1/2016
>   08:00
>
> booking_id: 3 booking_recurrence_id: 1 booking_date_time: 3/1/2016
>   08:00

I want to update the times to 09:00, so my expect result should be

> booking_id: 1 booking_recurrence_id: 1 booking_date_time: 1/1/2016
>   09:00
>
> booking_id: 2 booking_recurrence_id: 1 booking_date_time: 2/1/2016
>   09:00
>
> booking_id: 3 booking_recurrence_id: 1 booking_date_time: 3/1/2016
>   09:00

Comment: Could you be more specific and provide input data and expected output?

Comment: [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains `AddHours` method. Use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to update using EF (or any other ORM) is to retrieve the object, update it and then submit the changes.

There are multiple extensions that might do Batch updates, but it might not work in your case since you need to update based on the value of each row, and not update let's say all rows to some constant value.

However, you're doing one submit and you can also do 1 select in your case. But this will generate a number of update statements based on the number of objects.

1. Select all the recrods you want to update (1 round trip)
2. loop locally on the list of objects. (no trips to the database)
3. Update each object. (no trips to the database)
4. Submit the changes (1 round trip, multiple update statements generated)

I don't think you can generate a single Linq To SQL statement to do this. But you can go for a traditional T-SQL Query.

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>(); // your ids here. 

string commaDelimitedIds = String.Join("," ids);
string query = "UPDATE booking "
 + "SET booking_date_time = DATEADD(HOUR, 10, CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), CONVERT(DATE, booking_date_time))) "
+ "WHERE booking_recurrence_id IN (" + commaDelimitedIds + ")";

db.Database.SqlQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, not tested though

```
bookingToUpdate.ToList().ForEach(m => {DateTime.Parse( m.booking_date_time.ToShortDateString() + " 09:00 AM")})
```

Comment: Be aware !! This retrieved all the data locally to memory and then updates the objects. It should be avoided generally.

Comment: @user3185569 any reference...would like to look upon alternatives

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework you can look at [Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) . Batch Update feature - this is what you need. Each row can be updated based on its value.